# One Input source to run all context configuration one by one Target Single Oracle Table

Tags: talend

I am new user of Talend.

My requirement is I have a three Oracle DB connection "Test", "Pre Production", "Production". (User Name and Password of all three DB are different but Table and column name are same)

I had configure context for jobs for all DB connection by giving DB Information and able to run jobs in the Talend Open Studio. (For Employee tables, First I run "Test", then "Pre Production" and Production" Target is Single Oracle DB.

Below I have shown the flow,

TDBInput---> TlogRow---->TDBOutput (By using Insert option in the output, I manually run all jobs one by one and loaded all the data of Test, Pre production, Production Employee details into Target Oracle Table)

Now I have to schedule this job. I have schedule this job by using Task Scheduler. But At time of Schedule job is run Default Context only running at the time (ie Test data base only running will get only data of Test)

I need to run all three jobs and load into Oracle Database.

Could you please suggest.

If you need more details please let me know will provide additional info using visuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate your .bat/.sh job file that you are scheduling.
Edit it, you will see that at the end of the java command line, you have something like "--context=Default" . If you replace it by the name of your context in your job (ie Test,Pre production, Production) it will run with this group of context.
So you will have 3 different jobs, and you schedule each one of them.